# Store array of arrays in codigniter session

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a query in [CodeIgniter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codeigniter#CodeIgniter) model, like:

```
$query = $this->db->get('subscriber');
```

The above query is returning 474 rows as a result.

Now I want to iterate these value in my view in table format so I am storing the value in a [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP) native session, like:

```
 $_SESSION['list'] = $query;
```

But when I am iterating over this loop in view, I am not getting the desired result.

```
The value of $_SESSION['conn_id'] is '0'
The value of $_SESSION['result_id'] is '0'
The value of $_SESSION['result_array'] is 'Array'
The value of $_SESSION['result_object'] is 'Array'
The value of $_SESSION['custom_result_object'] is 'Array'
The value of $_SESSION['current_row'] is '0'
The value of $_SESSION['num_rows'] is '474'
The value of $_SESSION['row_data'] is ''
```

While using

```
foreach($_SESSION['list'] as $key=>$value)
{
        echo 'The value of $_SESSION['."'".$key."'".'] is '."'".$value."'".' <br />';
}
```

I know this is not the method to do this. How can I access the quesryset result in CodeIgniter view?

Can we use the queryset data directly or not?

Comment: Are you trying to store the results for future use to avoid another DB query? Or are you simply trying to return the results to the user? If the latter, @danneth has the precise answer.

Comment: @Wolf Good point, my interpretation was just getting data from model to view, but in case of persistent data it will of course not work without a session of some sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you would typically do is something like this

```
//model.php
class Subsrciber_Model extends CI_Model
{ 
    public function get_subscribers() 
    {
        return $this->db->get('subscriber');
    }
}

//controller.php
class Subscribers extends CI_Controller 
{
    public function subscribers()
    {
        $this->model->load('Subscriber_Model');
        $data = $this->Subscriber_model->get_subscribers();
        $this->load->view('view', $data);
    }
}

//view.php
<div>
    <?php foreach ($data->result() as $row): ?>
       <p><?=$row->conn_id?></p>
    <? endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$query = $this->db->get('subscriber')->result_array();
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that an array is being returned from your query? From the output of your `SESSION` it looks like you are treating an object like an array.

Try doing this in your model

```
$query = $this->db->get('subscriber')->result_array();
```